# I want to Convert HTML Table into PDF and CSV i am using node.js , angularJS and Big query to get data

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I want to Convert HTML Table into PDF and CSV i am using node.js and angularJS , I want to implement most efficient and fastest way to convert . Data is coming from big query because of that data is large Please suggest best way.

Please tell which way is good and why

- **To convert HTML table to pdf from front end**
- **Or to convert data on server side**

THANKS in Advance

Comment: Always server side, client side can be modified by receiver.

Comment: As far as I understand you don't want to convert a HTML into PDF or CSV. You're getting your data from a database and you want to create a PDF and a CSV. This should be done server side because there you can use better tools. If you want to convert a HTML into PDF, you can use pandoc on linux server.

Comment: OK Thanks Thomas Sablik

Comment: Do you try using https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer to convert html to pdf?